# Volume control lockout when Android apps is running

Tags: android, controls, volume

It seems that there are many postings for using **volume control** for apps.

What I want to do is to **lockout (disable) volume control** when a specific apps is running.

For example, if the apps triggers **alarm**, (in the alarm state) I don't want anyone to turn the **volume to zero**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just play it in the `ALARM` stream, which gives you the pre-set Alarm volume and intercept the volume buttons with `onKey`.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```